# Password-Hashing with Taylor Hornby (Defuse)'s Compatible version works with all PHP versions?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, password-protection, password-hash

I'm interested in using Taylor Hornby(aka Defuse)'s PHP password-hashing method (the PHP compatible version), which I found here: https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing

1. Does it work "safely" in PHP 4 and above?
2. Does it work safely in different servers? a 64-bit will give the same hashes as a 32-bit?

I'm asking this because different hosting companies provide different PHP versions and different Linux versions, that's why I'm afraid to implement this technique which might work just fine in my development server, but fails to work properly in production server.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Comment: @jww Why suggest this & not the recognized ircmaxell repository?

Comment: @Daryl - sorry, I don't know icrmaxwell or his framework. I do know SolarDesigner, I'm familiar with his work (like [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) and [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)), and know he's an expert in the field. SolarDesigner is also a judge for [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/).

Comment: @jww for the record, ircmaxell's library made it in PHP 5.5:  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: @Scott - I don't think that means much. Consider, PHP never uptook [Suhosin](https://suhosin.org/stories/index.html) (or hardened PHP). So I'm guessing they are uptaking projects to expand features, and security is not really a concern (or a secondary concern).

Comment: Exactly, you're just guessing. Why not look at https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat or https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/password.c and judge based on its real merits? I'm pretty sure [@solardiz](https://twitter.com/solardiz) would say that it's safe, but to be sure I'll ping him on Twitter.

Comment: evilReiko: "Different hosting companies provide different PHP versions", but surely none of them are still offering PHP4 (even when this question was asked, 11 months ago)?

Comment: @jww see https://twitter.com/solardiz/status/626245091896729600

Comment: @Scott -  I'm not sure what the point is. Are you offended I did not endorse one of your favorite pet projects? I know nothing about it, so I can't endorse it. (And I was guessing about PHP's criteria to uptake a project).

Comment: My point is that it's safe to use and saying things like "So I'm guessing they are uptaking projects to expand features, and security is not really a concern (or a secondary concern)" does not follow from the facts.

Comment: @Scott - you should point out PHP's criteria to uptake projects then. Its a simple matter of governance, and there should be published criteria, polices and procedures. As a matter of fact, PHP should have published an evaluation document when they adopted the ircmaxwell library explaining what the security goals were, how the library met the goals, and any potential gaps the library had. Like I said, its a simple matter of governance.

Comment: I'm not really part of Internals so put the onus on someone who was actually involved, like @ircmaxell for example. What you call "a simple matter of governance" I call "a lot of meaningless paperwork".

Comment: @jww PHP does not adopt libraries. The password hashing API was an RFC proposal for PHP (see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash). The compatibility library was later written by the author of the proposal, so people on older versions can use the same API.

Comment: @Scott - *"I call 'a lot of meaningless paperwork'..."* - and there we have it. Its the reason why people have to guess at times....

Comment: Just read the source code and decide from there. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work in PHP 4, as it requires either [`hash_pbkdf2`](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/83a208748c29135704bf13130d52254fbc2bb001/PasswordHashClass.php#L117) ([available in PHP 5.5+](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)) or [`hash_hmac`](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/83a208748c29135704bf13130d52254fbc2bb001/PasswordHashClass.php#L128) ([available in PHP 5.1+ or PECL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)).

It will work the same in 64-bit, as well as 32-bit.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> Does it work "safely" in PHP 4 and above?

This question was asked in 2014; there's no excuse for running PHP 4 at that point in time. Please [update to a supported version of PHP (e.g. 5.6)](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php) as soon as possible. If this is out of your control, boycott your hosting provider (and name names, please, so we can pressure them to update).

> Does it work safely in different servers? a 64-bit will give the same hashes as a 32-bit?

Yes, Defuse's code works well regardless of platform architecture. But that's not the real answer to this question.

The best answer anyone can provide is that you should use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify), which are designed for passwords and will be forward-compatible with new algorithms when the current default (bcrypt) is rendered obsolete (e.g. by scrypt or Argon2, the [Password Hashing Contest winner](http://www.password-hashing.net)).

These functions are available in PHP 5.5.0 and newer, or 5.3.7 and newer with [ircmaxell/password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (written and maintained by the author of the functions used in PHP 5.5).

If you're using an older version of PHP, your best option is to use [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hosted with Domain.com, and I was shocked that they don't support so many common PHP stuff, they use PHP 4, old phpMyAdmin, no support for crontab, plus so many other problems. But I have to mention their technical response is fast and satisfying. I think they've upgraded PHP to version 5 just recently.

Comment: Domain.com eh? Target acquired >:]